# align HTML controls in grid

Tags: html, css

I have this html form:
[image]

I would like to arrange it in this way:
[image]

how can I do that using HTML and CSS?

Comment: you can use table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please insert your code **but in general i think you need to use a grid system to divide your viewport to two columns and align text to the left.**